# Compare current row value with next row value in php

Tags: php, mysql

```
ID UserID    Payment_Date  Expired_Date      Diff(Payment_Date&Expired_Date)

 1  123   2017-08-01 00:00:00  2018-01-01 00:00:00             
 2  123   2018-02-01 00:00:00  2018-10-01 00:00:00              31    
 3  123   2018-10-05 00:00:00  2018-10-10 00:00:00              4
```

How to compare first row expiry date with second row payment date . I need to show result like Diff(`Payment_Date`&`Expired_Date`) 31,4 .

Comment: You need to refine this question to properly display your sample data. I don't see you ask any clear question here. Most of all, I don't see any research effort or anything that you have already tried doing so far...

Comment: You want it done in PHP or MySQL query???

Comment: @KKK I need in PHP

Answer (score 0):

No need PHP, You can do this in SQL

```
SELECT ID, UserID, Payment_Date, Expired_Date, lastpayement, DATEDIFF(lastpayement, Expired_Date) AS DIFF
FROM
(
    SELECT m.ID, m.UserID, m.Payment_Date, m.Expired_Date, 
            (
                SELECT Payment_Date
                FROM mytable tt
                WHERE  m.Expired_Date < tt.Payment_Date AND tt.UserID=m.UserID
                GROUP BY UserID
            ) AS lastpayement
    FROM mytable m
) t
```

Results

```
| ID | UserID |         Payment_Date |         Expired_Date |         lastpayement |   DIFF |
|----|--------|----------------------|----------------------|----------------------|--------|
|  1 |    123 | 2017-08-01T00:00:00Z | 2018-01-01T00:00:00Z | 2018-02-01T00:00:00Z |     31 |
|  2 |    123 | 2018-02-01T00:00:00Z | 2018-10-01T00:00:00Z | 2018-10-05T00:00:00Z |      4 |
|  3 |    123 | 2018-10-05T00:00:00Z | 2018-10-10T00:00:00Z |               (null) | (null) |
```

[SQLfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/178938/8)

Comment: There's a lot of query here. Just sayin'

Comment: Thanks @thomas. Its a useful answer